# Visual Studio doesn't open command window for console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, console-application

I see a light blue bar in Visual Studio saying "Ready" when I debug or run my code, but the command window doesn't open. What should I do for the command window to appear?

Comment: You'll need to show us some code, edit your answer to include some so we can help.

Comment: Did you set the Console Application as startup proejct?

Comment: are you sure it doesn't open and close? otherwise are you trying to run a process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is probably finishes its job so fast, that you dont notice the command window. Add `Console.ReadKey();` at the end of your main function.

That is assuming you actualy run an exe file.